# Не срабатывает метод .play(). В чем причина?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

При клике на кнопки таймер запускается и ведёт отсчёт корректно, но когда время заканчивается аудио не воспроизводится.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

class TimerWrapper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        timeLeft: null,   // Указывает на оставшееся время. Изначально равен null
        timer: null       // Отсылается на наш таймер. Изначально равен null
      };
    }

    startTimer(timeLeft) {   // Вызывается при нажатии на button
      clearInterval(this.state.timer);  // Избавляемся от запусков нескольких таймеров одновременно при нажатии на разные кнопки
      let timer = setInterval(() => {
        let timeLeft = this.state.timeLeft - 1;  // Отнимает 1 секунду от оставшегося времени
        if (timeLeft === 0) {    // Если оставшееся время равно 0,
          clearInterval(timer);  // очищаем таймер, чтоб таймер не уходил в минус
        }
        this.setState({
          timeLeft: timeLeft   // timeLeft из строки 10 равен timeLeft из строки 17
        });
      }, 1000);
      return this.setState({timeLeft: timeLeft, timer: timer});
    }

    render() {
      return(
        <div>
          <h2>Timer</h2>
          <div>
            <Button time = '5' startTimer = {this.startTimer}/>
            <Button time = '10' startTimer = {this.startTimer}/>
            <Button time = '15' startTimer = {this.startTimer}/>
          </div>
          <TimerDisplay timeLeft = {this.state.timeLeft}/>
          <audio id = "end" preload = "auto" src = "../media/Barely Alive - Doggo.mp3"></audio>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  class Button extends React.Component {
    handleStartTimer() {
      return this.props.startTimer(this.props.time)
    }
    render() {
      return <button onClick = {this.handleStartTimer.bind(this)}>
        {this.props.time} секунд</button>
    }
  }

  class TimerDisplay extends React.Component {
    render() {
      if (this.props.timeLeft === 0) {
        document.getElementById("end").play()
      }
      if (this.props.timeLeft === 0 || this.props.timeLeft === null) {
        return <div></div>
      }
      return <h1>Осталось {this.props.timeLeft} секунд</h1>
    }
  }


ReactDOM.render(<TimerWrapper />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Продолжил искать проблему, выяснил, что аудио не воспроизводится только с локального диска. С внешних ресурсов (VK, Mail Облако) аудио воспроизводится без проблем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для импорта локальных файлов нужно использовать следующий подход:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


import audioSRC from "./media/linkin_park-faint.mp3";

class TimerWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      timeLeft: null,   // Указывает на оставшееся время. Изначально равен null
      timer: null       // Отсылается на наш таймер. Изначально равен null
    };
  }

  startTimer(timeLeft) {   // Вызывается при нажатии на button
    clearInterval(this.state.timer);  // Избавляемся от запусков нескольких таймеров одновременно при нажатии на разные кнопки
    let timer = setInterval(() => {
      let timeLeft = this.state.timeLeft - 1;  // Отнимает 1 секунду от оставшегося времени
      if (timeLeft === 0) {    // Если оставшееся время равно 0,
        clearInterval(timer);  // очищаем таймер, чтоб таймер не уходил в минус
      }
      this.setState({
        timeLeft: timeLeft   // timeLeft из строки 10 равен timeLeft из строки 17
      });
    }, 1000);
    return this.setState({timeLeft: timeLeft, timer: timer});
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>Timer</h2>
        <div>
          <Button time = '5' startTimer = {this.startTimer}/>
          <Button time = '10' startTimer = {this.startTimer}/>
          <Button time = '15' startTimer = {this.startTimer}/>
        </div>
        <TimerDisplay timeLeft = {this.state.timeLeft}/>
        <audio id="end" preload="auto" src={audioSRC}></audio>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Button extends React.Component {
  handleStartTimer() {
    return this.props.startTimer(this.props.time)
  }
  render() {
    return <button onClick = {this.handleStartTimer.bind(this)}>
      {this.props.time} секунд</button>
  }
}

class TimerDisplay extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.timeLeft === 0) {
      document.getElementById("end").play()
    }
    if (this.props.timeLeft === 0 || this.props.timeLeft === null) {
      return <div></div>
    }
    return <h1>Осталось {this.props.timeLeft} секунд</h1>
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<TimerWrapper />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Я перепробовал разные пути и распихал аудиофайлы на разных уровнях папок. Всё равно не работает( Может ли быть дело в доступе браузера к локальных аудио файлам? Хотя запускал этот и на Chrome, и на Firefox, и на Opera, и на Edge - нигде не работает

Comment: Обновил ответ для локальных файлов

Comment: Получилось! Огромное спасибо))